# C++ 64 bit file i/o gotchas

Tags: c++, linux, 32bit-64bit

I found an interesting bug when converting C++ app from 32 to 64 bit Linux.
Our FileStore class implements saving/restoring structs to/from file.
It always calls fopen() and fclose() before and after each operation except in one method. 
In this (buggy) method on 32-bit platforms, it can fseek() and fread() without error even though the file has been previously fclose()'d by other methods. On 64-bit platform it crashes every time on fread().
I guess that on 32-bit platform the underlying FILE struct persists even after the fclose() so it can still be accessed.
Does anyone have any further info on why this difference and any other gotchas to do with 64bit file i/o?

Comment: Undefined behavior is ALWAYS subject to change. Performing operations on an `fclose`d stream is UB. see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html

Comment: One can still wonder what it is about the two different implementations that results in the different behaviour, especially if that behaviour appears consistent in both cases.

Comment: Yes, it is the consistency of the behaviour that is curious. It could just simply be that the 64bit GCC 4.1.2 runtime always cleans up the FILE struct after fclose(), and the 32bit doesn't, but I kindof expected the runtimes would follow the same low-level steps.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like undefined behavior to me. The 64 bit vs 32 bit aspect of your question is a red herring. The compiler is free to erase your home directory, or maybe file your federal tax return in such circumstances.

Comment: Indeed it is, this issue is not about 64 bit vs 32 bit - it's just pure (un)luck. Every test case here, using a FILE* after it's fclosed results in a crash, 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: it is "After the call to fclose(), any use of stream results in undefined behavior." From

Comment: Thanks - I agree you can't rely on what happens if you use a FILE after you've fclose()'d it; as you say maybe just dumb luck on 32bit that it wasn't cleaned up immediately. Probably you're right that the 64bit is a red herring ... just curious as we're going through a 64bit conversion exercise and don't want to miss anything.